# How can artificial intelligence (including deep learning algorithms) find suspicious patterns in the body’s biochemistry?

Tags: deep-learning, healthcare, learning-algorithms

It has been [suggested](http://www.itnonline.com/content/will-fda-be-too-much-intelligent-machines) that machine learning algorithms (also [Watson](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1427/8)) can help with finding disease in patient images and optimize scans. Also that deep learning algorithms show promise for every type of digital imaging.

How does exactly deep learning algorithms exactly can find suspicious patterns in the body’s biochemistry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't focus *only* on "deep learning" unless you have some specific reason for doing so.  There may be other techniques which could be as effective, or more effective.

One approach I've seen used for something similar was [Inductive Logic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_logic_programming).  For one example of using ILP to reason about elements of biochemistry, see [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224309517_Estimation_of_Possible_Reaction_States_in_Metabolic_Pathways_Using_Inductive_Logic_Programming)

That's not exactly about detecting disease, but it does sort of illustrate the broad idea of reasoning about states and reactions involving metabolic pathways in biochemistry, using ILP.   Possibly the basic idea could be adapted more towards detecting disease.